# What happens to the time period when refraction occurs?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, refraction, frequency, wavelength

I was studying light and had a doubt that when refraction occurs (rarer to denser just assuming) then frequency remains same but lambda (wavelength) and velocity decrease. But I cant quite figure out what happens to the time period. does it increase because velocity decreases.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59469/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21336/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frequency is the inverse of the period. So since the frequency is the same the period is also the same