# The light behavior from vacuum to glass

Tags: optics, refraction, frequency, boundary-conditions

[image]

What does the statement labelled mean? This is in Feynman's lectures on physics. Why should the frequency in both vacuum and glass be same?

What is the meaning, that charge sitting on the boundary will feel only one frequency? What role does charge on the glass play in this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the frequency of light change during refraction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59469/)  (for example.  many more)