# Frequency and wavelength of a plane wave perpendicularly entering a material with n>1

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I just realized that I am not entirely sure as to what happens with the wavelength and the frequency of an optical plane wave when entering for example glass (e.g. monochromatic laser).
The refractive index of a material is given by  $n = \frac{c_0}{c}$, the Helmholtz equation tells us: $k_n = n\frac{\omega_0}{c_0}$ (and the group velocity is given by $v_g = \frac{\partial \omega_n}{\partial k_n}$) where the n-indexed variables are related to the medium with refractive index n. 
 Now using Helmholtz one can derive that $\lambda_n=\frac{\lambda_0}{n}$, meaning the wavelength gets reduced.
On the other hand we would have $f_n\lambda_n=c_n$, implying $f_n=\frac{c_n}{\lambda_n}=\frac{\frac{c_0}{n}}{\frac{\lambda_0}{n}}=\frac{c_0}{\lambda_0}=f_0$ 
 This in turn would imply that the frequency of the wave remains the same. 
I am somehow in need of a sanity check as to whether my deduction makes any sense or not.

Comment: Related question: [Why doesn't the frequency of light change during refraction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59469/why-doesnt-the-frequency-of-light-change-during-refraction)

Comment: Frequencies never change when going from one material to another, because the frequency represents the *time-dependence* of each point in the medium, and a single point (at the interface!) can't have two different frequencies.

Comment: @march This makes sense, thanks. So even if the (perpendicularly to the laser beam propagation direction) scattered light of a laser beam in a piece of glass looks green, it does not mean that the laser beam itself is green inside the glass?

Comment: a nonlinear medium *may* change the frequency, from a pure tone $\omega_1$it will generate its  harmonics $n\omega_1; n=1,2,3...$,  and from a pair of tones $\omega_1, \omega_2$ it generates its intermodulation terms $n\omega_1+m\omega_1; n,m=\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3,...$, etc.

Comment: @velo "green inside the glass" does not really mean anything. The quality of being green is a physiologic effect. The colour of light makes sense only inside the eye or actually on the retina.  Only the frequency of the light reaching the retina matters for the resuling impression of colour.