# Why doesn't frequency change when the medium of the wave changes, and only depend on the source of the wave?

Tags: waves, refraction, frequency, wavelength

When the medium of the wave changes, the velocity and the wavelength does change, but not frequency, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the frequency of light change during refraction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59469/)