# Amplitude of light across material boundaries

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

Does the amplitude of the light ray decrease when it moves from a rarer to a denser medium?

I think that since amplitude depends upon the energy of the light ray, it should decrease. This is because of the kinetic energy of the light wave decreases (velocity decreases as light travels from rarer to denser medium), hence the energy of the wave falls.

This explanation does not seem convincing, could anyone provide some insights?

Comment: duplicate of several questions

Comment: Could you please provide me with a link that will lead me to that answer?

Comment: Maybe  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22385/  or http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21336/  . The point is that $ E = h\nu $ and frequency does not change.

Comment: But then you are treating light as a particle whereas refraction is a wave phenomena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fresnel's equations sum up the behaviour of light across medium boundaries in terms of linear dielectric response. This problem was solved in the 19th century.

Answer (score 0):

The amplitude of the electric field in the medium depends on the medium's permittivity, which is not directly related to its density.

> Kinetic energy of the light wave decreases(velocity decreases as light travels from rarer to denser medium), hence the energy of the wave falls.

This is not true -- the energy in an electromagnetic wave does not depend on its velocity. Additionally, the speed depends on the permittivity and permeability, not the density.

Comment: Is the same true for sound?