# Refraction of light

Tags: visible-light, refraction

In a prism, violet light undergoes more refraction than light of higher wavelength. Is there any explanation as to why light of higher frequencies refract more than light of lower frequencies?

Comment: Yes there is. But it takes the best part of a year in a upper-division E&M class to develop the formalism to show it. How is your vector calculus and differential equations? Without that it comes down to someone telling you that various optical parameters are functions of frequency and *this* is how the dependence goes.

Comment: Feynman explains the introduction to this phenomenon nicely: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_31.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65812/

Comment: @dmckee---ex-moderatorkitten, 4 years after asking this question, I am halfway through Griffiths' E&M (self-study though) and beginning to understand what this is leading to.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at this is to go to the definition of the index of refraction
$$n = \frac{c}{v}$$
v is related to the wavelength and frequency as
$$v = \lambda f$$
So the index of refraction becomes
$$n = \frac{c}{\lambda f}$$
[Frequency remains the same when light goes into a new medium,](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22385/why-does-wavelength-change-as-light-enters-a-different-medium) so the only difference between light of different colors is the wavelength. The lower wavelength of violet light will give a greater value for n, and so light will be refracted more.

Comment: I find it interesting that you emphasize (correctly) that frequency is the property of the light waves that remains the same on transitions through material media, but also write the dispersion in the wavelength-dependent form. From the raw math of Maxwell's Equation it is clear that the *frequency* is the proper independent variable, but we have this long running historical tendency to write it in terms of wavelength (and then insist "vacuum wavelength!" to overcome the silliness that would otherwise ensue). Any way, thus endeth my rant.