# Why does frequent remain constant in refraction?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, refraction, frequency, boundary-conditions, wavelength

---

So at school the told us that:
V= f x λ

---

In refraction we were told that direction,speed and wavelength changes when a wave crosses different mediums, and on another occasion that frequency is the number of waves that pass at a given point per second

---

so if the wavelength and speed changes, doesn’t that cause a decrease or increase of the number of waves passing the point per second aka frequency?
Please clear up the confusion for me :)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22385/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It is just that frequency stays the same, that if speed changes  wavelength changes accordingly since $\lambda=c/f$ "frequency is the number of waves that pass at a given point per second" is wrong. " You have frequency of one wave, so there is no number of waves passing a point. A wave  is an oscillation with frequency f which propagates , so at every point a wave reaches  you have an oscillation

Comment: @trula thank you this makes sense ヾ(＠⌒ー⌒＠)ノ