# Color in Different media

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, frequency, wavelength

When a light wave passes from one medium to other, the wavelength of the light wave changes and the frequency remains constant.
If then color of the light waves depends on changing wavelength or Frequency?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21336/ and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer -

Frequency ($\nu$) stays constant since it is a characteristic property of the source. Using the relation $v = \lambda \nu$ in the definition of the refractive index, $n = c/v$, your required answer follows.