# Does colour of light depend on intensity of light?

Tags: visible-light, frequency, wavelength, absorption

By intensity I mean frequency of light

Comment: "By intensity I mean frequency of light" ... intensity and frequency are *not* the same. Which do you really mean ? Colour depends on wavelength, which is related to frequency, but it does not depend on intensity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What determines color -- wavelength or frequency?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21336/what-determines-color-wavelength-or-frequency)

Comment: This pile-up of negative votes is unfair.

Answer (score 2):

No, only on the wavelength. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum .

Comment: The OP claims that they mean "frequency" when they say "intensity" which is not only confusing but makes your answer incomplete.  In general it is best to try and clarify a question (using comments to the OP) before answering ambiguous questions like this.